# 'Object' is undefined with calendar.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, calendar

I have this line in my JS it is working fine in IE, but in Firefox it's giving an error "document is undefined" . I got this error by using firebug, see the line and help me to come out from this

```
x = event.layerX+document.documentElement.scrollLeft; 
y = event.layerY+document.documentElement.scrollTop;
```

I am trying to make the devshed tutorial for JavaScript Object lesson to work in my PC.

The calendar.js file has the object 'Calendar' constructed but when I called using the below html doc, I get the

> Calendar' is undefined error for line 6 and 7, where the obj1 and obj2
>   are specified.

The full code of the calendar.js is in
http://www.devshed.com/Client_Side/J...ect/page9.html
Both the files are in the same directory. I am using Windows 2000
Professional with IE6.
Appreciate any help to resolve this problem.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" src="calendar.js"></script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<script> obj1 = new Calendar(2, 2005); </script>
<script> obj2 = new Calendar(7, 2001); </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your file src="" path is correct one.
check if file is included or not ?

Answer (score 0):

are you using jquery in this ? or have you try to go with firebug to check particular DOM Object error ?

Comment: are you using jquery in this ? or have you try to go with firebug to check particular DOM Object error ?
           console.log();return false;